# How to initialize dictionary inside class constructor

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class with a property of type `Dictionary<>`. I am trying to initialize the property in the constructor using the following code. It gives error. Why?

**Error 1**

> 'Permissions' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

**Code:**

```
public class UserModel
{
    public UserModel()   // constructor
    {
        Permissions = new Permissions<Guid, List<Guid>();
    }

    public Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you *are* trying to use `Permissions` as a type. You meant `Dictionary` obviously...

Comment: +1 from me, just because of the downvotes. It may be a beginner question, but at least it contains all required information to answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create instance of property. Instead you need to create instance of a type and assign it to property.

```
public class UserModel
 {
    public UserModel()   // constructor
    {
        Permissions = new Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>>();
    }
    public Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>> Permissions { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
    public class UserModel
    {
       public Dictionary<Guid, List<Guid>> Permissions { get; set; }
       public UserModel()   // constructor
       {
           Permissions = new Dictionary<Guid,List<Guid>>();
       }

    }​
```

Comment: That was already in the previous answer. And *try this* isn't very helpful.

Comment: First of all, you can't disable my account. Second, I didn't down vote, so you are barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: As I said, it was only 2 minutes different between my posting and the previous. I often takes 10 minutes to properly prepare a response so duplicate answer sometimes occur.